# Problem with vanish | When a player quit and rejoin, he can see me (while i'm vanished) | Minecraft Plugin Java

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm having issues with my command /vanish: while i'm vanished, and a player join the game after my vanishing, he can see me. Here the code of the command and of the PlayerJoinEvent + updateVanish():

```
        if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("vanish")) {
        if (player.hasPermission("vanish.permission")) {
        if(!vanish.contains(target)) {
            vanish.add(target);
            
            if (player == target) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Ora sei in " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE +  "Vanish" + ChatColor.BLUE+ ". Nessuno ti potrà vedere");
            } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Hai Impostato " + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + target.getName() + ChatColor.YELLOW + " in " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Vanish");
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Ora sei in Vanish. Nessuno ti potrà vedere");
            }
            for (Player persone : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                if (!persone.hasPermission("visible.vanish")) {
                    persone.hidePlayer(this, target);
                }
            }
        } else {
            vanish.remove(target);
            for (Player persone : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                persone.showPlayer(this, target);
            }
            if (player == target) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Ora non sei in " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE +  "Vanish" + ChatColor.RED+ ". Tutti ti potranno vedere");
            } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Hai disattivato " + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + target.getName() + ChatColor.YELLOW + " dal " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Vanish");
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Ora non sei in Vanish. Tutti ti potranno vedere");
            }
        }
        } else {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Non hai il permesso di usare questo comando");
        }
        return true;
        }
```

Here the PlayerJoinEvent + updateVanish():

```
    @EventHandler
public void OnPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    updateVanish();
}

public void updateVanish() {
    for (Player persone : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (vanish.contains(persone)) {
            for (Player persone2 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers() ) {
                persone2.hidePlayer(this, persone);
                
            }
            
        }
}
}
```

Thanks <3!

Comment: did you register the event?

Comment: Where i need to register the event?

Comment: at onEnable(), put this line: `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);`

Comment: I had already done that

Comment: Sorry! In onEnable() i don't writed @Override! Now works!

Comment: the `@Override` shouldn't change anything, maybe the name of the function wasn't correct.

Comment: I writed OnEnable instead of onEnable. It was the problem?

Comment: yes, methods are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by creating an List containing all currently vanished players and then once a new player joins, use the PlayerJoinEvent to iterate trough all currently vanished players and vanish them for the newbie using:
Player.hidePlayer(t)

I currently do not own the tools to build proper code but if you are still indoubted after reading the above, I can detail better.